# Does the Soul Stone always require a sacrifice to work?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, infinity-stones, avengers-endgame

Does the mechanics of the Soul Stone always require a sacrifice?

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Red Skull tells Thanos that the Stone requires a sacrifice, a soul for a soul.  Would someone who hasn't paid the price for the Stone be able to use it?

Comment: **Red Skull:** *In order to **take** the stone you must lose that which you love. A soul...For a soul.*. Presumably he means to take it from its hiding place

Answer (score 15):

Red Skull said that you had to make a sacrifice in order to take the Stone ([script source](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War)), not to use it.

From *Endgame*, we can infer that

> If the Soul Stone did require a sacrifice in order to function, Tony wouldn't have been able to snap Thanos out of existence.

Comment: Of course, person X, above,  grabbed it off of __, who grabbed it off of __, etc. It seems like it only applies to taking it from Vormir.

Comment: My rationale is that the character in the spoiler sacrifices himself by using (and in order to use) the Stone (nothing said that the sacrifice has to take place on Vormir). This does not apply to Thanos in *Infinity War* (and that other character in *Endgame*) since they are protected by the Gauntlet.